# Set up an SFTP server

Tags: ssh, sftp, 23.04

I'm following this guide to set up an SFTP server on Ubuntu 23.04: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-setup-sftp-server-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

I have a question about this step where the guide tells us to create a new user, `sudo useradd -m sftpuser -g sftp`, why do I need to create a new user? Can't I use my existing account and add myself to the `sftp` group? Ex: `usermod -a -G sftp existingUser`

Lastly, I don't want the SFTP folder to exist in `/home/sftpuser/`, I want it to be on my desktop: `/home/existingUser/Desktop/sftp`. Is this possible?

Comment: The `useradd` command the `-m` switch means to create the user home directory if one doesn't exist, so if it does exist you should be fine there.  The `-g` switch means to add the user to the `sftp` login group.  The answers can be found when running `man useradd` or `man usermod`.  Either command listed there should work fine.  As far as using the desktop directory that should be set in the config file for sftp.